# Using R, how can I see if any word from a list of words is contained within a group of columns?

Tags: r

I have a dataset, where I want to see if there is one of any word in a list within a number of columns.

```
zoo <- matrix (c("zoo1", "bee", "honeybee", "alligator", "tiger", 0,  
             "zoo2", "tiger", "honeybee", "lion", 0, 0,
             "zoo3", "alligator", "alligator", "alligator", 
           "bee", "wasp", "zoo4", "wasp", "honeybee", 0, 0, 0,
           "zoo5", "alligator", "lion", "tiger", "bear", 0), 
           nrow = 5, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(zoo) <- c("zoo", "A", "B", "C","D","E")

zoo <- data.frame(zoo)
```

I'd like to create a new column that identifies each row that contains a bug (bee, honeybee, or wasp). Here's what I tried:

```
#create list of values that would return "TRUE" in the new column
bug <- c("bee", "wasp", "honeybee")

#create list of columns to be included in the search for the list of desired values
animal <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

#create a new column called "bug" that lists any row with one of the desired values as "TRUE"
zoo$bug <- (rowSums(zoo[,animal] == bug) >0)
```

This only partially worked. Zoo1, Zoo3, zoo4, and zoo5 are correct, but zoo2 (row 2) comes up as "FALSE" when it should come up as "TRUE". I can't figure out why this would be the case.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can use %in% instead of == when there are multiple values (though that change is not a full answer to this problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like

```
rowSums(sapply(zoo[,animal], function(x) x %in% bug))
```

to count bugs in rows, and ...

```
apply(sapply(zoo[,animal], function(x) x %in% bug), 1, any)
```

to see if there are any bugs in a row.

Comment: thanks @lebatsnok, I used the second option and it seems to have worked perfectly. I was banging my head against the wall for a couple of hours - thank you!